# What is the maximum thickness of walls that a hog rider can jump over?

Tags: clash-of-clans

What is the maximum thickness of walls that a hog rider can jump over?
A hog rider can be seen in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oONjC7tBAlg#t=4m7s) leaping over a triple wide wall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no official number, and user tests suggest it may be limitless; Hog Riders are just meant to jump walls, no matter how thick.

On supercell's user forums people like [this guy](http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/194759-Limit-hog-rider-jumping-distance) have done user tests and complained that it appears the wall thickness doesn't matter, the hogs will jump it regardless. It is important to note this post was made in January 2014, Hog Riders could be patched at a later date.

Comment: In that case hogrider would seem to be flying like a dragon over walls. Because landing on wall would seem weird

Answer (score 0):

The jump range depends on their level from hog rider level 1 that can jump a range of 5 to the hog rider of level 5 that can jump 7 walls. This increases every level.

Comment: If it increases at every level why wouldn't a level 5 hog be able to jump 10 walls? (Base wall jump + level (5) = 10)

Comment: it isen't adding a wall every level but some levels (i beleve level 3 & 5)

Comment: If this is true we need a source

Comment: that's just a thoght because they also change physical appearance at those levels, I don't know if it is true tough!

Comment: This is not true.

Comment: how can you tell?

Answer (score -1):

Hog riders have a 5-10 jump range.

Comment: 10 seems a bit much... can you provide some evidence to support this?

Comment: Ten is an exageration usually 5-7 sorry

Comment: Ok, and you say 5-7. What determines what distance they can jump? Their level I'm assuming?